# Cannot Get Pascal's Triangle Recursive Program to Work --Java

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array, runtime-error, pascals-triangle

I'm trying to write a program for an assignment. The requirements are to create Pascal's Triangle recursively and then print a given line. However, after compiling my program, I get several ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions. Here is the stack trace:                                                                          `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10 at pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:79) at pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:86) at pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:86) at pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:86) at pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:86) at pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:86) at pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:86) at pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:86) at pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:86) at pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:93) at pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:86) at pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:86) at pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:86) at pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:86) at  pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:86) at pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:86) at pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java: 93) at  pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:86) at  pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:86)at  pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:86)at  pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:86)at  pasTriangle.populateT(pasTriangle.java:86)`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've tried everything, esp changing condiionals but nothing works. Here is my code:

```
    public class pasTriangle
{

    private int size, row, col;                                                         //Represents the number of lines the triangle has.

    private int [][] pTriangle;                                                 //2-D array to hold int values of triangle





    /* ****************************************************************************************************************************************************

            Constructor creates a 2D array to hold the Pascales triangle. Note the number of numbers on each line is the same as the number of lines in
            the triangle, so size can be used for both values. Calls populateT method to populate the triangle.

        ***************************************************************************************************************************************************/



    public pasTriangle(int size)
    {
        this.size = size;

        pTriangle = new int[size][size];


    }       


        /* ****************************************************************************************************************************************************

            Method which populates the Pascal's Triangle recursively. Note case where size = 1, recursion does not occur since only 1 integer can be added
            to array.
            Also note base case where base of triangle is reached and recursion stops.
            Also note cases for first and last value of each line (row).

            Appropriate values added to each index according to conditions.


        *********************************************************************************************************************************************************/
    public void populateT(int row, int col)
    {


        if(size > 0 && size == 1 && row < size)
        {
            pTriangle[0][0] = 1;
        }


        else if(size > 1 && row < size)                     
        {
            if (col==0 && row == 0)                                                             //First value.      
            {
                pTriangle[row][col] = 1;
            }


            else if (row != 0 && col == 0 || col == pTriangle[row].length-1)
            {
                pTriangle [row][col] = 1;                                                       //1 Set for first value in each line and last value in each line.

            }

            else if(row > 1 && col != 0 && col != pTriangle[row].length-1)                      //Values in between first and last calculated from the two above them, to left and right.
            {
                pTriangle[row][col] = (pTriangle[row-1][col-1]) + (pTriangle[row-1][col+1]);      
//Line 79, exception here.

            }


            if (col < pTriangle[row].length && row < pTriangle.length)  //Move over and give values to indexes recursively until end of row is reached
            {    **//Line 87, exception here.**
                populateT(row, col+1);      

            }

            else if (col >= pTriangle[row].length && row < pTriangle.length)    //If end of row is reached and number of rows is not exceeded.
            {   
                col = 0;                                        //Col reset.   
**//Line 93 Exception here.**
                populateT(row+1, col);  
            }


        }


    }



    /* ***********************************************************************************************************************************************

            Prints a string containing the values on a given line of the pasTriangle. Note 1 is subtracted from lineNumber to get correct index.

        ***********************************************************************************************************************************************/


    public String getLine(int lineNumber)
    {
        lineNumber = lineNumber - 1;
        String result = "";

        for(int biz = 0; biz < pTriangle[lineNumber].length; biz++)
        {
            result += Integer.toString(pTriangle[lineNumber][biz]);

        }

        System.out.println(result+"/n");

        return result;

    }

}
```

{

```
public static void main (String [] args)
    {


        try{
        pasTriangle T1 = new pasTriangle(1);
        pasTriangle T2 = new pasTriangle(9);
        pasTriangle T3 = new pasTriangle(3);
        pasTriangle T4 = new pasTriangle(5);            //Triangle with only one line created (so not a triangle); test for condition size == 1.

        T1.populateT(0, 0);
        T2.populateT(0, 0);
        T3.populateT(0, 0);
        T4.populateT(0, 0);




        T1.getLine(1);
        T2.getLine(4);
        T2.getLine(9);                  //Test for last line.
        T3.getLine(1);                  //Test for first line.
        T3.getLine(2);
        T4.getLine(1);                  //Test for first line.
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   



}
```

Comment: For future reference, its sometimes nice to have the lines that error indicated in the code, since we cannot see line numbers.

Comment: Ok I've added comments to show line 79, line 86, and line 93

Comment: It looks like your row is going out of bounds. e.g. Row+1 = 10, but max rows is 9. I'd just put a simple check at the beginning to see is the row is going to be out of bounds, and if so just return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ArrayIndexOutOfoundsException` appears to be coming because this line allows the recursion to continue with an invalid `row` index.

```
else if (col >= pTriangle[row].length && row < pTriangle.length)
```

The `row` variable could be `pTriangle.length - 1`, and then you call `populateT(row+1, col)`, passing `pTriangle.length` into the recursive call.  Then that recursive call eventually attempts to access an invalid `row` index, causing the exception.  Changing it to `row < pTriangle.length - 1` will solve the immediate exception problem.

The condition directly above it, `row < pTriangle.length`, controls when to move to the next column, but you don't need it here; you're not modifying `row` here.

Also, you will want to stop the column recursion when you match `row`, not when you match the physical end of the `row`, so *both* conditions need to change.  Change `if (col < pTriangle[row].length && row < pTriangle.length)` to `if (col < row)`, and `else if (col >= pTriangle[row].length && row < pTriangle.length)` to `else if (col >= row && row < pTriangle.length - 1)`.

Above those conditions, similar changes are needed in the code to determine whether to write a `1` or add the relevant numbers from the row above.  Change `else if (row != 0 && col == 0 || col == pTriangle[row].length-1)` to `else if (row != 0 && col == 0 || col == row)` and `else if(row > 1 && col != 0 && col != pTriangle[row].length-1)` to `else if(row > 1 && col != 0 && col != row)`.

When you add the previous row's elements to write a non-`1` value, it appears you're adding the wrong elements.  Assuming that a valid data structure would look like this...

```
[1][0][0][0]
[1][1][0][0]
[1][2][1][0]
[1][3][3][1]
```

You need to add the element above and to the left to the element directly above.  Change `(pTriangle[row-1][col-1]) + (pTriangle[row-1][col+1]);` to `(pTriangle[row-1][col-1]) + (pTriangle[row-1][col]);`.  (The `col+1` changes to `col`.)

If you change your output code in `getLine` to add a space, you'll be able to verify your numbers better.  Also, `println` already prints a new line after your parameter, so you don't need to append a newline character (which is `\n` instead of `/n`).

Comment: Thanks this was really useful. Somehow I have never really worked with 2D arrays so I think that was part of the reason why I had a hard time visualizing why I was going out of the bounds of the array.